# What is the name?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

```
 0,4 ;  2,4 ;  2,0 ;  0,0 ; 0,1
 3,0 ;  3,4 ;  5,4 ;  5,0 ; 3,0
 8,0 ;  6,0 ;  6,4 ;  8,4
 6,2 ;  8,2
 9,4 ;  9,2 ; 11,2 ; 11,0 ; 9,0
11,4 ; 11,2
```

The above is the first name of a famous tv character. What is this first name?

Comment: Thereby **knowledge** tag is essential for this puzzle.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay That won't be necessary at all. The puzzle could be asked as **what is this name?**. I just chose the name of that character (so decided to add that trivial information which doesn't help solve the puzzle in any way).

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay The only knowledge you need is in those numbers above. Knowing that tv character or not has no effect on solving the puzzle.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay you could argue knowledge is applicable to every question, but read the tag info, and you'll see that it isn't needed for every puzzle as your recent comments suggest. It is only for puzzles which can't be solved without it

Comment: A specific first name need not be the first name of only a famous TV artiste. It can be the first name for many. I feel this supporting question adds to more uncertainty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like

> JOEY (originally from Friends) when the points are connected as Cartesian coordinates

An image is the best I can parrot from online spreadsheet

> [image]